# ERROR: Extra trailing closure passed in call - NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, swift5, swiftui-navigationlink

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?
The error is on this line " NavigationLink(destination: LazyView(LocationViewNearby(locationNew: locationSTR)){". It happens when I try create a navigation link.

And I get these errors:
"Extra trailing closure passed in call"
"Missing argument for parameter #1 in call, Insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>, '"

Code Below (NearbyView):

```
ForEach(mapData.places){ place in

let locationSTR = String(place.placemark.name ?? "")
    
NavigationLink(destination: LazyView(LocationViewNearby(locationNew: locationSTR)){
    
    LocationViewNearby(locationStr: locationStr)
    
    Text(place.placemark.name ?? "")
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    
    Text((place.placemark.locality ?? "") + ", " + (place.placemark.country ?? ""))
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    
})

   Divider()
}
```

Code with no errors (LocationViewNearby):

```
import SwiftUI

 struct LocationViewNearby: View {

var locationNew: String


//@ObservedObject var viewModel = NearbyView()





var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ScrollView{
          
            
            PostGridView(config: .location(locationNew))
        }
    }.padding(.top)
    // .navigationBarTitle(locationNew, displayMode: .large)
    //above for the large menu tab, check which is nicer
    .navigationBarTitle(locationNew, displayMode: .inline)
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to create a `NavigationLink` to a view that you are already displaying? Also, what is the code like in `LocationViewNearby`

Comment: Hi, I am trying to go to a different view and pass a variable into it. The LocationViewNearby view code has been uploaded. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you also add the code for `LazyView`? I guess what we need is a minimal reproducible example that we can verify it here by ourselves.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem in your code - it's just a typo. Here is a missing closing parenthesis: `LazyView(LocationViewNearby(locationNew: locationSTR)))`

Comment: @Cuneyt , I feel so stupid lol. It works now, thanks for the help!